# Keras flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use keras flow_from_dataframe in order to augment the input images to my network (I am using the latest keras_preprocessing version). The network has an input image and an image as a label. I have a csv file in the following format that specifies the input-output:

```
Input,Output
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\1.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\2.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\3.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\4.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\5.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\6.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\1\7.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\1.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\104\1.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\104.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\104\10.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\104.JPG
E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Dataset\104\11.JPG,E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\Dataset_Part1\Label\104.JPG
```

I am trying to load the csv to a dataframe  by the following code:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"E:\LTM\SCIE_DB\dataset.csv",names=("Input","Output"),dtype={"Input":"str","Output":"str"})
df = df.astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)

datagen=image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=None, x_col="Input", y_col="Output", class_mode="other", target_size=(32,32), batch_size=32,has_ext = True)
```

However, I keep getting the following error :

```
TypeError: y_col column/s must be numeric datatypes.
```

No matter what I am doing, I am unable to set the y_col as a str and it is always an object type. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that str is not a numeric type, y_col should be integers or floating point, not string.

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, y_col can be a string.
From:
https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
y_col: string or list, column/s in dataframe that has the target data.

Comment: I mean the value of y_col can be a string, but the column it refers to has to be numeric since you specified class_mode to "other".

Answer (score 0):

Your values for  y_col are of "string" type, but in your code you have refereed it as "numeric" since you specified class_mode as:

```
class_mode="other"
```

So change the class mode to

```
class_mode="input"
```

so you can use "string" values for y_col

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's issue, it is better to add context, or an explanation as to why this solves the OP's problem, so future visitors can learn from your post, and apply this knowledge to their own issues. High Quality Answers are much more likely to be upvoted, and contribute to the value of SO as a platform.